# can't connect my Visual Studio to Mac Pro to develop Xamarin IOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't connect my Visual Studio XAMARIN.IOS project on Windows to my Mac Pro.
I have not connected for about two months.  Worked perfect back then.

I get this error...

> visual studio mono version installed on Mac may not be compatible with
>   this version of visual studio. Would you like us to install Mono 5.16

[image]

When I clicked "Install", I got this error...

[image]

Is there a solution to getting Visual Studio to install Mono 5.16 or must I do it manually?

macOS is 10.13.6

Mac Xcode is 10.1

Visual Studio 2017 Pro is 15.9.7 on Windows 10

Target iPad is connected to Mac.

Comment: And what have you done?  Both of those error dialogs suggest resolutions, have you tried them?

Comment: Just update both visual studios(mac and win) to latest and it will work

Comment: I don't have VS on the mac.  But I will update my windows VS... Actually VS 15.9.7 is the latest version.

Comment: @DougNull you should install latest version of Xamarin tools in mac in then, download the latest version of Xamarin for visual studio. They both must have the same version to properly work

Comment: Umm i do not think it is possible to debug apps with just the MAC the MAC must have a Visual studio installed in it for it to work

Comment: @G.hakim No need right now. Install `Xamarin.iOS` and `Mono` in Mac is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waited a long while, restarted all computerts, made sure all were latest versions, and Visual Studio then automatically updated mac Mono.